Junit code for Kafka and Mongo standalone core java
I am having a core java application (standalone not springboot) to read a json message from Kafka topic, parse json, map source fields to target fields(field A in Kafka message might be field B in mongo collection) and write it to mongo collection. Everything works fine.
Now I want to write Junit test cases for Kafka, mongo and mapping classes.
In all the forums I am seeing samples with springboot and mockito. Please share any sample/references for core java code.

Please share what you have tried so far and why it isn't working

1. Test Kafka
For Kafka, you can use the EmbeddedKafka class from the spring-kafka-test library, even in a non-Spring Boot application:
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.kafka.test.EmbeddedKafkaBroker;
import org.springframework.kafka.test.context.EmbeddedKafka;
import org.springframework.kafka.test.utils.KafkaTestUtils;

import java.util.Map;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

@EmbeddedKafka(partitions = 1, topics = { "testTopic" })
public class KafkaTest {

    @Test
    public void testKafka() {
        EmbeddedKafkaBroker embeddedKafka = new EmbeddedKafkaBroker(1, true, 1, "testTopic");
        embeddedKafka.afterPropertiesSet();

        Map<String, Object> producerProps = KafkaTestUtils.producerProps(embeddedKafka);
        ProducerRecord<String, String> record = new ProducerRecord<>("testTopic", "key", "value");
        KafkaTestUtils.getKafkaProducer(producerProps).send(record);

        Map<String, Object> consumerProps = KafkaTestUtils.consumerProps("testGroup", "true", embeddedKafka);
        ConsumerRecord<String, String> received = KafkaTestUtils.getSingleRecord(
                KafkaTestUtils.getKafkaConsumer(consumerProps, new StringDeserializer(), new StringDeserializer()), "testTopic");

        assertEquals("value", received.value());
    }
}


Test MongoDB

For MongoDB, you can use the Testcontainers library to spin up a MongoDB instance for testing
import org.bson.Document;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.testcontainers.containers.MongoDBContainer;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClients;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

public class MongoTest {

    private static MongoDBContainer mongoDBContainer;
    private static MongoClient mongoClient;

    @BeforeAll
    public static void setUp() {
        mongoDBContainer = new MongoDBContainer("mongo:4.4.3");
        mongoDBContainer.start();
        mongoClient = MongoClients.create(mongoDBContainer.getReplicaSetUrl());
    }

    @AfterAll
    public static void tearDown() {
        mongoClient.close();
        mongoDBContainer.stop();
    }

    @Test
    public void testMongo() {
        MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("test");
        MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("testCollection");

        Document doc = new Document("name", "testName");
        collection.insertOne(doc);

        Document retrievedDoc = collection.find().first();
        assertEquals("testName", retrievedDoc.getString("name"));
    }
}


Test mapping classes

For mapping classes, you can write simple unit tests using JUnit
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

public class MappingTest {

    @Test
    public void testMapping() {
        Source source = new Source("fieldAValue");
        Target target = new Target();
        target.setFieldB(source.getFieldA());

        assertEquals("fieldAValue", target.getFieldB());
    }

    class Source {
        private String fieldA;

        public Source(String fieldA) {
            this.fieldA = fieldA;
        }

        public String getFieldA() {
            return fieldA;
        }
    }

    class Target {
        private String fieldB;

        public void setFieldB(String fieldB) {
            this.fieldB = fieldB;
        }

        public String getFieldB() {
            return fieldB;
        }
    }
}



Testcontainers works for Kafka too

yes that's true
